# clone div is not draggable after it is copied

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

i have two `divs`
one `div` is where all the `components` are i am moving them to my `board` div ,
and once there i can copy those `divs`,
 but once a div is copied it is not movable any more

here is an example:
[What i have so far can be viewed here](http://plnkr.co/edit/OlIJtXR5sBIPBB2pjc6w)

so what i am trying to achieve is once a div is copied i should be able to move that copied div around as well

in-order to copy a div select one of the div inside the board and then hit the button copy (do note the button is a bit buggy might need to press a few times)

- the desirable output is
  when a component is dragged in to the board 
  and once that component is selected and the button "copy" is clicked
  the selected div should be copied and should also be draggable

**Update**
what i noticed in my code 
when i copy a div it is not draggable, but when i place another div from the component side to the board everything becomes draggable

Comment: in your given snippet all div are draggable. Unable to understand what is not working?

Comment: @AlivetoDie please check again

Comment: @AlivetoDie once i drag the div inside the board and select one of the div
and press the copy button (the button is a bit buggy might need to press a few times)
the div which is copied but is not draggable.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers

Comment: Is still see no code in your question - please read this: [Something on my website doesn't work, can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).  It also applies when pasting links to external coding sites

Comment: That's a link now isn't it, and not **in the question itself**  please read my comments more carefully otherwise this question is off topic for SO due to the reason in my first comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.You need to add `$(".new_item").draggable();` in your `copy` button `click` event handler.

2.Also you need to refine your code so that `copy` and `delete` will work properly in one click

do like below:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $(".component_item").draggable({
      helper: 'clone',
      cursor: "move"
    });

    $("#board").droppable({
      accept: ".component_item",
      drop: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).append($(ui.draggable).clone());
        $("#board .component_item").addClass("new_item");
        $(".new_item").removeClass("ui-draggable component_item");
        $(".new_item").resizable({
          handles: "all",
          autoHide: true
        });
        $(".new_item").draggable({});
      }

    });
    $( "#copy").click(function(e) {
        $(".new_item:last").clone().appendTo("#board");
        $(".new_item").draggable();
        $($this).css("border-style","solid");
    });
    $( "#delete").click(function(e) {
        $(".new_item:last").remove();
        $($this).css("border-style","none");
    });

  }); //    \\End--Ready
</script>
```

Output:- http://plnkr.co/edit/MiG1lfG8sqJsPngbPuxQ?p=preview